# Getting TextField dimensions with adobe flash AS2

Tags: flash, adobe, actionscript-2

I am trying to create a TextField, populate it with some text and get this text dimensions, but when i am trying so:

```
var baka:TextField = new TextField();
baka.autoSize = true;
baka.htmlText = 'Hello World!';
trace(baka.textWidth); // undefined
trace(baka._width); // undefined
```

all i am getting by `.textWidth` and `._width` is `undefined`. Why it may be so and how to fix that?

Comment: If I remember correctly, in as2 you instantiate a TextField object using the [createTextField()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as2/reference/flashlite/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118ccf9c47f-7b78.html) method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AS2 requires the use of the `createTextField` method call.  AS3 provides the ability to instantiate a TextField object and add it to the stage as you were trying to do.

Here is an AS2 example that should work for what you are trying to do with AS2.

```
var baka:TextField = _root.createTextField("baka",stage.getNextHighestDepth(),10,10,200,50);
baka.autoSize = true;
baka.htmlText = 'Hello World!';
trace(baka.textWidth);
trace(baka._width);
```

Please note the following:

1. You will need to change `_root` to match the object you are attempting to add the `TextField` to.
2. The width and height parameters in the `createTextField` method call won't mean anything if you set the `autoSize` property of the TextField to true